# Lookup function in VB6

Tags: vb6

I have a table in an excel file called " Employee_States_File".This table contains two columns Name and States. Both columns are filled with data. The province table contains abbreviation of the States such as " NE, WA" and so. I have another excel file called " States_File" which contains a table that has two columns: Abbreviation and FullStateName. This table is considered to be a lookup table to look for the full state names based on the abbreviation. Now, I want to write a code in VB6 so that when the user click a button, All the abbreviation names in the table of the excel file " Employee_States" are changes into the full state names based on the lookup table of the excel sheet " States_File".
does it make sense?
Please help,

Comment: These are Excel files? XLS or XLSX? Why not use the [Excel VLOOKUP function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx) and do it directly in Excel?

Comment: I did use the VLOOKUP function. however, It is driving me crazy because it works around half of the records and then it gives me an error as:"Unable to get the vlookup property of the Worksheet function class" . I was told that this error means that the VLOOKUP function did not find a match of a value in the first column of the lookup table. when I changed that value manually and replace it with a value that was previously found, it still hangs there. I don't know why it gives me that error message. I am using XLS files. any idea? . I can't do it directly in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to convert them to csv files (comma delimited text files) you can use the Jet Database engine and do normal SQL joins.

I use this to setup the connection.

```
Public Function OpenTextConnection(ByVal FileName As String) As Connection
    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
    Dim DBFolder As String
    Dim TS As TextStream

    Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
    DBFolder = FSO.GetParentFolderName(FileName)

    If FSO.FileExists(FSO.BuildPath(DBFolder, "Schema.ini")) Then
        FSO.DeleteFile (FSO.BuildPath(DBFolder, "Schema.ini"))
    End If

    Set TS = FSO.CreateTextFile(FSO.BuildPath(DBFolder, "Schema.ini"))
    TS.WriteLine "[" & FSO.GetFileName(FileName) & "]"
    TS.WriteLine "Format=CSVDelimited"
    TS.WriteLine "ColNameHeader = True"
    TS.WriteLine "MaxScanRows = 0"
    TS.Close

    Set OpenTextConnection = New Connection


    If FSO.FolderExists(DBFolder) Then
        OpenTextConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & DBFolder & ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;"";"
    Else
        MsgBox DBFolder & " Does not exists.", vbExclamation
    End If

End Function
```

Each file is a table in the connection and you can do SQL joins. Note the example is just a simply open up a table. You can use any valid SQL Syntax.

```
Dim DB1 As Connection
Dim TB As Recordset
Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
Dim tImport As New DBImportList
Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
Set tImport = New DBImportList
If FSO.FileExists(FileName) Then
    Set DB1 = OpenTextConnection(FileName)
    Set TB = New Recordset

    TB.Open "SELECT * FROM [" & FSO.GetFile(FileName).Name & "]", DB1, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

End If
```

Comment: Is there a way to use the .xls file without converting them to csv?

Comment: only if the user has Microsoft Office installed. You can use the com libraries that Excel exports to access .xls files directly. I don't recommend this for simple table lookup as it introduces unneed eddependencies.